# GTFS - how to combine the protocol buffers and GTFS file?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, gtfs

I am trying to look at the [New York City Subway Realtime GTFS Feeds](http://datamine.mta.info/list-of-feeds).  After a lot of reading around, I learned about [Protocol Buffers](https://github.com/google/protobuf/) and installed the `protoc` compiler.

New York City Transit has the file [`nyct-subway.proto.txt`](http://datamine.mta.info/sites/all/files/pdfs/nyct-subway.proto.txt) the first line says *NYCT Subway extensions for the GTFS-realtime protocol*.  Is this supposed by be combined with **[`gtfs-realtime-proto`](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/gtfs-realtime-proto)**?  I compiled the two protocol buffers separately and got the warning:

```
[libprotobuf WARNING google/protobuf/compiler/parser.cc:471] 
No syntax specified for the proto file. 
Please use 'syntax = "proto2";' or 'syntax = "proto3";' to specify a syntax version. (Defaulted to proto2 syntax.)
```

In Python wrote a line to call on whatever library `protoc` had created:

```
import gtfs_realtime_pb2, nyct_subway_pb2
```

Despite my previous installation effort, Python didn't know anything about `import google.protobuf` So it do `sudo pip install protobuf`.

At this point I am still not reading any data -- I can get a gtfs file with `http://datamine.mta.info/mta_esi.php?key=<key>&feed_id=1` which is unreadable.

**How do I combine this to read the data from the GTFS file?**

Comment: The nyct-subway.proto file depends on the gtfs-realtime.proto file at protoc compile time. So once protoc generates Python code from those .proto files, you should be able to just import that generated python code and use a generated class called FeedMessage or transit_realtime.FeedMessage in your code. This code is what decodes the binary feed response into an instance when you call FeedMessage.FromString(s), where s is the raw feed response.

Answer (score 2):

To further clarify Jamie's comment, you should be able to do something like this:

```
import urllib2
import gtfs_realtime_pb2, nyct_subway_pb2

... 

    // initialize the feed parser
    feed = gtfs_realtime_pb2.FeedMessage()

    // fetch the raw gtfs-realtime feed
    gtfs_raw = urllib2.urlopen("http://datamine.mta.info/mta_esi.php?key=<key>&feed_id=1").read()

    // parse the raw feed
    feed.ParseFromString(gtfs_raw)

    // access the data structure as needed
    print feed.header.timestamp
    print feed.header.gtfs_realtime_version

    for entity in feed.entity:
        // etc.
```

---

## Alternate Method (Command Line + JSON)

Personally, I think protocol buffers and gtfs-realtime can be a pain. To skip the work, I wrote a standalone tool to convert GTFS-realtime into JSON:
https://github.com/harrytruong/gtfs_realtime_json

Just download (no install), and run: `gtfs_realtime_json <feed_url>`

Here's a sample [JSON output](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/harrytruong/gtfs_realtime_json/master/samples/bart-trip-updates.json).

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two together by using the `protobuf` Python package.
Download both `.proto` file and place it into `docs/gtfs_proto`, create a `gtfs_proto` folder for the output and then run:

```
export SRC_DIR=docs/gtfs_proto
export DST_DIR=gtfs_proto
protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --python_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/nyct-subway.proto
```